# Slow down progressbar progression

Tags: android, multithreading, while-loop, android-canvas

I am using this  code here to loop and update progress on a custom progressbar.

```
class MyThreadRunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
     int count = 0;
        public void run() {
            try {
            while (count < 90) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                count += 1;
                 progressBar.setProgress(count);
                 progressBar.setText(count + "%");
            }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
 };
```

When it gets closer towards the end I want it to start slowing down,is this possible without have to make another while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just change the sleep time for values over 90?

```
    class MyThreadRunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
     int count = 0;
        public void run() {
            try {

            while (count < 100) {

                //500 is half a second...
                int sleepTime = count < 90 ? 10 : 500;
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

                count += 1;
                 progressBar.setProgress(count);
                 progressBar.setText(count + "%");
            }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyThreadRunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
     int count = 0;
     int sleepTime = 0;
        public void run() {

            while (count < 100) {
                sleepTime = count < 90 ? 10 : 100;
                Thread.sleep(sleeptime);

            }


 };
```